# Fixed div as solid with 100% height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to go with the css-only approach to this issue and not to use `margin-left` to move the `<div class="fd"></div>` from `<div class="sb"></div>`
I've ran out of the idea-fuel what to try. I've nested some wrappers and used different kinds of positionings *(this is not a typo nor French, spell-checker excuse me)* but nothing has worked out so far.

*Issue:* Making a fixed div as solid element, to accept the `.fd` element on it's right side.

`.fd` holds content which is going to exceed the height of the page.
`.sb` holds side-content which is going to remain as 100% in height.

See snippet for a clear example what I've been struggling with.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sb {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  background: blue;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.fd {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline;  /* Won't apply to fixed? block will overlap everything */
}
```

```html
<div class="sb"></div>
<div class="fd">
  <p>Am I out in the open?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You want something to toggle, yet you're aiming not to using JS? Will this happen on hover? There's not that much more you can do with just CSS. What do you want to toggle this change? Also what is "RWD editing"?

Comment: That wasn't a part of the main process, just an idea what I will be implementing. Input-level elements can be used for toggle-like changes. RWD editing - Responsive Web Design editing.

Comment: So, what's your actual question? How to toggle something? Or just how to position the div to the right? You can clearly already do what you've put in the title of your question and it's kinda hard to work out what you're asking.

Comment: Removed the blathering, updated post. Main issue is with the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added an extra `.wrap`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap{
  padding-left: 300px;
}
.sb {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  background: blue;
  margin-left: -300px;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.fd {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline;  /* Won't apply to fixed? block will overlap everything */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap" id="wrap">
  <div class="sb"></div>
  <div class="fd">
<p>Am I out in the open?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/tb3pbam9/

Comment: Definitely works, I had this idea go through my mind before as I said earlier usage of margin-left (padding-left in this case) would be the last straw. If anyone doesn't have a better way of solving this issue this will be the answer. Originally my idea was to have `.sb` as fixed with a solid property without it being wrapped with `.fd`